# PHP date format symbols vs JAVA date format symbols

Tags: java, php, date

It seems that PHP uses other date format symbols than Java to format a date based on a pattern. 
E.g. when I want to output a date like this:

```
17.03.2014 09:50
```

In PHP, I have to use the date format pattern

```
d.m.Y H:i
```

while in Java, I use the pattern

```
dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm
```

Is there a Java class, that can convert a given input (Java) pattern to the PHP pattern, e.g. convert `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm` to `d.m.Y H:i`? I'm asking, because I have to use a Javascript [date picker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) which uses the PHP date format symbols to format a date.

Comment: I don't understand your justification. On the client side you use this JS date picker which uses the php date format. Where exactly do you need to convert one pattern into the other?

Comment: Server side creates the HTML stuff with JAVA and there i got a method like `getDateParser().getDatePattern()` which returns the correct JAVA date pattern based on language, which used in fact the Java date format symbols mentioned above. I just would like to call a class like `JAVAtoPHPDateFormat.convert(getDateParser().getDatePattern())`.

Comment: I see. I'm afraid I'm not aware of any such libraries. Generally speaking, if possible, I'd strive to keep server side concerns insulated from client side ones to avoid any unnecessary coupling. Namely, I'd do the conversion in JS. Also, as stated by @MenoHochschild in his EDIT below, look at JSR-310.

Comment: @Rooboo (a) Please edit your question to add info or clarify, rather than comments. (b) I'm confused why you are mixing Java with PHP. If you have Java on the server-side, why not use Servlets and lose the PHP? (c) If you are passing date-time values as formatted strings between user-interface code and business-logic code, don’t. Stick with a true date-time object in business logic. In Java that means either Joda-Time or java.time. When crossing outside of Java, use unambiguous strings defined by ISO 8601 & [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there is no Java class which does this conversion. You have to write your own from the scratch according to your needs.

Note: Every programming language uses its own pattern dialect. Even Java has since version 8 TWO different pattern styles, but no conversion between them!

Supplementary EDIT:

You should also keep in mind that conversion is not always possible due to the limitations of underlying different format and parse engines. Furthermore, sometimes a break and introduction of new pattern dialects can be justified, see the design decision of JSR-310 for a more CLDR-like and more powerful pattern dialect in Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is one I wrote, it relies on the JodaTime library.  I haven't done in depth testing on every case, so make sure it works for you.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateUtils {
    private static final String[] daysOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    private static final String[] daysOfWeekShort = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat"};
    private static final String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    private static final String[] monthsShort = {"Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    private static final String[] daysInMonth = {"31", "28", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31"};
    private static final String[] suffixes = {"st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th",
                                              "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th",
                                              "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th",
                                              "th", "th"};

    /*
        Works like PHP Date function, has support for most characters.  Time zone offsets mainly what is missing.
     */
    public static String format(DateTime dt, String format){
        int pos = 0;
        char[] charArray = format.toCharArray();
        int length = charArray.length;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (pos < length){
            switch(charArray[pos]){
            // Days
                case 'd':
                    sb.append(dt.getDayOfMonth() < 10 ? "0" + dt.getDayOfMonth() : dt.getDayOfMonth());
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    sb.append(daysOfWeekShort[dt.getDayOfWeek()]);
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    sb.append(daysOfWeek[dt.getDayOfWeek()]);
                    break;
                case 'j':
                    sb.append(dt.getDayOfMonth());
                    break;
                case 'N':
                    sb.append(dt.getDayOfWeek() + 1);
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    sb.append(suffixes[dt.getDayOfMonth() - 1]);
                case 'w':
                    sb.append(dt.getDayOfWeek());
                    break;
                case 'z':
                    sb.append(dt.getDayOfYear());
                    break;

            // Weeks
                case 'W':
                    sb.append(dt.getWeekOfWeekyear()); // Needs confirmation
                    break;
            // Months
                case 'F':
                    sb.append(months[dt.getMonthOfYear() - 1]);
                    break;
                case 'M':
                    sb.append(monthsShort[dt.getMonthOfYear() - 1]);
                    break;
                case 'm':
                    sb.append(dt.getMonthOfYear() < 10 ? "0" + dt.getMonthOfYear() : dt.getMonthOfYear());
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    sb.append(dt.getMonthOfYear());
                    break;
                case 't':
                    int moy = dt.getMonthOfYear();
                    if (moy == 2 && dt.getYear() % 4 == 0) { sb.append("29"); }
                    else { sb.append(daysInMonth[moy]); }
                    break;
            // Years
                case 'Y':
                    sb.append(dt.getYear());
                    break;
                case 'y':
                    sb.append(dt.getYearOfCentury());
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    sb.append(dt.getYearOfCentury() % 4 == 0 ? 1 : 0);
                    break;
            // AM/PM
                case 'a':
                    sb.append(dt.getHourOfDay() < 13 ? "am" : "pm");
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    sb.append(dt.getHourOfDay() < 13 ? "AM" : "PM");
                    break;
            // Hours
                case 'g':
                    sb.append(dt.getHourOfDay() % 12);
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    sb.append(dt.getHourOfDay());
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    sb.append(dt.getHourOfDay() < 10 ? "0" + dt.getHourOfDay() % 12 : dt.getHourOfDay() % 12);
                    break;
                case 'H':
                    sb.append(dt.getHourOfDay() < 10 ? "0" + dt.getHourOfDay() : dt.getHourOfDay());
                    break;
            // Minute
                case 'i':
                    sb.append(dt.getMinuteOfHour() < 10 ? "0" + dt.getMinuteOfHour() : dt.getMinuteOfHour());
                    break;
            // Second
                case 's':
                    sb.append(dt.getSecondOfMinute());
                    break;
            // Timezone
                case 'e':
                    sb.append(dt.getZone());
                    break;
            // Any other character
                default:
                    sb.append(charArray[pos]);
            }
            pos++;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```